# Create a function that counts number of time the exact word occurs in string

Tags: python, function

well, I'm new to python and trying to Create a function that counts number of time the exact word occurs in string. this is my python code :

```
def fsi(s):
    count = 0
    for word in s.lower().split():
        if word == 'ali':
            count += 1
        return count
```

when i call fsi function it doesn't work properly and the returned number isn't correct. it just returns 1 not anymore

```
fsi('ali and ali and ali!')
```

what do you propose me to fix it ?

Comment: Change the indentation of the line `return count` so that it's outside the for loop and at the end of the function. The issue is that you're trying to return within the loop, so it'll always return 0 or 1 since it'll return on the first occurrence.

Comment: Along with the above problem, note that the last item the iteration will be `ali!`, not `ali`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate he said his problem was that it always returns a count of 1 instead of the actual count. This is because of the incorrect indentation of the return statement. However you raise a good point - checking for equality of the word will not catch the last occurrence.

Comment: Be certain you know what format the input string will be. You're currently assuming word boundaries will always be spaces or start/end of string. As pointed out by Carcigenicate, the last "word" is `ali!` so it won't count it. Similarly, if the string was "ali, ali, and ali!" the count would come out as 0 with the current logic. You might want to look into regex and word boundaries if you want a more general approach for counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Correct way 1:

```
import re
len(re.findall(pattern, string_to_search))
#Usage 
len(re.findall('\bali\b', s))
```

#### Correct way 2:

```
s = "ali and ali and ali!"
s.count('ali')
```

Comment: Without `\b` word boundaries, your regex will count `aligator` as a match. The `s.count('ali')` has the same problem: That will count the sequence of characters `ali` even if part of another word.

Comment: i put the string in "" like this : fsi("ali and ali and ali !") and it worked correctly

Comment: You have a space between `'ali'` and `'!'`

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\bali\b', 'ali and ali and ali!')
['ali', 'ali', 'ali']
```

If you use Python string routines, you will need to strip the various forms of punctuation. Otherwise `ali==ali!` will be `False`.

To do this with Python string routines, you could do:

```
>>> s='ali the aligator is called ali!'
>>> sum(1 for w in [''.join([c for c in word if c.isalpha()]) for word in s.lower().split()] if w=='ali')
2
```