# Python .count String function - Counting an exact word occurrence from string or line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, count

I want to count the word occurrence from a string. But I only want to count the exact occurrence, not from a substring.

For eg. If the string which I want to count is -> "This is good" and If the word I want to count the occurrence is "is", I only want to get occurrence of is to be 1 not 2. But my code counts "is" from "This" word. How can I do this. Sorry for my poor english.

```py
text = "This is good"
text.count("is")

>>> 2
```

```py
text = "This is good"
text.count("is")

>>> 1
```

Comment: `text.count(" is")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a function that counts number of time the exact word occurs in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600717/create-a-function-that-counts-number-of-time-the-exact-word-occurs-in-string)

Comment: You can try this: `text.split(" ").count("is")`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use this method you can just insert space(if you will alway searching for the word)

```
text = "This is good"
print (text.count(" is"))
```

output:

1

the better **solution** will be:

```
text = "This is good"
num = text.split().count('is')
print (num)
```

output:

1

to make this counter be **case-insensitive**, for example in this case:

```
text = "Is this ok, it is just example is"
num = text.lower().split().count('is')
print (num)
```

output:

3

> The **method lower()** returns a copy of the string in which all
>   case-based characters have been lowercased.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> ```
> str.lower()
> ```
>
> The **split() method** splits a string into a list.
>
> You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.
>
> Note: When max is specified, the list will contain the specified
>   number of elements plus one.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> ```
> string.split(separator, max)
> ```

Comment: `"Leave it like it is"` will return 0

Comment: `"is it a solution?"`

Comment: in this case it will probably be "Is it a solution?" ,secntence starts with capital an "is" not the same as "Is". this are all special cases which OP didnt define @OlvinRoght

Comment: It's regular cases, nothing special.

Comment: its different if he count "is" or "Is" or both

Answer (score 1):

You first must get the individual words by splitting the string by whitespace:

```
words = text.split()
```

Now sum all of the items in the list where the word equals the string you are checking:

```
sum(char for char in words if char == string_to_check)
```

In a function, you obtain the following:

```
def count(string, check):
    return sum(char for char in string.split() if char == check)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression, it'll help you to find substring divided with any word boundary:

```
import re

text = "This is good is\tis\t"
occurences = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r"\bis\b", text))
```